# AWS Application Load Balancer with OneLogin Giving 561 Authentication Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, onelogin

I am trying to integrate with OneLogin using an AWS Application Load Balancer. I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.onelogin.com/blog/aws-alb-openid-connect). I can go through the onboarding flow, but when I finish entering my information the page yields a `561 Authentication Error`.

**Load Balancer Information**

It's configured with a security group that:

- Allows all ingress traffic from the internet on HTTP and HTTPS.
- Allows outbound traffic from anywhere on HTTPS.

It listens on HTTPS: 443, with a valid SSL cert. This listener has a rule for OIDC authentication that's configured as follows:

```
Authenticate using OIDC
Issuer: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc
Token endpoint: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token
User info endpoint: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/me
Authorization endpoint: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/auth
Session cookie: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie
Session timeout: 604800
On unauthenticated: authenticate
Scope: openid profile
```

(client ID and client secret omitted)

After this it points to a target group that routes to an ECS instance. Without this authentication step, the ECS instance works as expected and the application appears.

**Response Information**

Request Headers, after login (identifying information omitted):

```
:authority: ***
:method: GET
:path: /oauth2/idpresponse?code=***&state=***
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
referer: https://***.onelogin.com/login2/?return=***
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers:

```
content-length: 558
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 09 Jul 2020 17:08:10 GMT
server: awselb/2.0
status: 561
```

I'm just kind of stumped on what part of the flow things are going wrong. The docs for AWS ELBs state this about 561 error codes:

> HTTP 561: Unauthorized
> You configured a listener rule to authenticate users, but the IdP returned an error code when
> authenticating the user.

So I imagine something is going wrong with the OneLogin part. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I got access to the application configuration and found that the Token Endpoint was set to Web instead of POST. Updating it correctly solved the problem. Thank you!